# изменение размеров изображения пропорционально изменению, ширины ее родителя

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть написал такой вот скрипт, даже поставил, чтобы функцию запускалась, с интервалом в 100мс, при изменении размеров экрана, картинка масштабируется, как надо, но если расширять или сужать окно быстро, или изменять ориентацию экрана, то картинка замирает, пока я не начну менять ширину окна, или пока не обновлю страницу. Как исправить проблему? Как сделать чтобы функция работала ровно?

```
jQuery(function($) {

    setInterval(
      function slide() {
        var wid = parseInt($('.node-property.node-promoted.view-mode-full .group-left').css('width'));
        if(wid<650){
            $("li.gallery-slide img").css('width', wid);
            };
        if(wid<570){
            $(".galleryformatter .gallery-slides").css('width', wid);
            }
        else{
            $(".galleryformatter .gallery-slides").css('width', 520);
            }
        }, 100);
      $(window).resize(slide);
      $(document).ready(slide);


    });
```

Comment: Зачем все это?.почему не изсользовать css для этих целей? http://shpargalkablog.ru/2012/06/kartinka-po-razmeru-ekrana-css.html

Comment: у вас функция slide внутри другой функции, вынесите её. а в setinterval напишите просто её имя setInterval(slide,100)